# Bootstrap 3 Modal Placement in HTML Markup

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The Bootstrap ([docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)) say to "always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality."

Does this mean to place modals at the very top of my `<body>` tags? If so, why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A '*top-level position*' does not necessarily mean first, it means that it needs to be near the top of the DOM tree.

**Examples:**

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="modal"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is not at the top of the DOM, because `div#modal` is *inside* `div#content`.  So we have this DOM tree:

```
body
 +-> div#content
      +-> div#modal
```

**Another Example:**

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- Content goes here -->
  </div>
  <div id="modal"></div>
</body>
```

Although `div#modal` is not at the top of the page, it's at the top of the DOM tree:

```
body
 +-> div#content
 +-> div#modal
```

Answer (score 5):

It's mostly to avoid conflicts. When you place modals below the elements which trigger them you might have noticed that sometimes the close button will not work properly. In order to avoid those conflicts, its recommended to place it on top of `HTML DOM tree` as mentioned by MTCoster in his answer.

Comment: "on top of HTML" is vague...it makes it sound like you would put it outside of your `<html>` tags, which would be invalid HTML. Clarify that to make it less ambiguous, then comment me, and I'll remove my -1.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks for notifying