# opening a modal using datatable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm so confused what the problem in my code is. I've already tried [this 
working code](https://jsfiddle.net/t53cyutt/3/) but it doesn't work for me.

I've also already tried `'toggle'` and that doesn't work either.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $("#inbox_modal").modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered inbox" style="width:100%">
  <div class="modal fade" id="inbox_modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content modal-form">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Example</h4>
          <a data-dismiss="modal" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>POP UP ME!!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap, aren't you? What's version you use?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your development console and is your Javascript code in a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: i use bootstrap and version is 4

Comment: Have you imported the bootstrap .js file and jQuery in your code?

Comment: @Lewis no error detected :/

Comment: @frank yup already import cuz i tried with button and it works

Comment: Try placing your Javascript in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @lewis i forgot to mention is already inside of that code

Comment: FWIW, the code in the fiddle is Bootstrap 3. I haven't been able to get this to work in BS4 for a while either.

Comment: The `<table>` is not closed.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742274/bootstrap-3-modal-placement-in-html-markup/23742609#23742609) - you should not be placing your modal code that far down the DOM tree

Comment: where is your tr tag in code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind click event to button from ajax result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944236/how-to-bind-click-event-to-button-from-ajax-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine. Just fix markup of the table and make sure the Bootstrap components are included to your page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $("#inbox_modal").modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>

 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered inbox">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Click</td>
      <td>here</td>
      <td>please</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="inbox_modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content modal-form">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Example</h4>
        <a data-dismiss="modal" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>POP UP ME!!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>` this components im using now . when i try your link my DataTable Jquery is not working

Comment: @Del, the link from my post for the Bootstrap. It was necessary to show you the snippet works. To use DataTables plug-in you have to add it to your page too.

Comment: im sorry, i mean i add your link to my code and DataTables not works well :'( doesnt show search pagination etc..

Comment: @Del, you could use DataTables [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/) to include all necessary components.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work on my end. You have to display `tr` a row where the user could click and show the modal.

Here added on your code `<td><tr><tr></td>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $("#inbox_modal").modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered inbox" style="width:100%">
  <tr><td><td></tr>
  <div class="modal fade" id="inbox_modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content modal-form">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Example</h4>
          <a data-dismiss="modal" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>POP UP ME!!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</table>
```